# Running a Runnable from inside an enum constant to play a sound

Tags: java, audio, enums, runnable

How to successfully run a runnable inside an enum constant to play a sound?

I have the following code:

```
public enum SystemSounds {

    ALERT(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            kit.beep();
        }
    }) // End of alert sound

    ; // End of enum constants

    private Runnable r;

    SystemSounds(final Runnable r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void play() {
        r.run();
    }

}
```

What is supposed to happen is when I call `SystemSounds.ALERT.play()` the beep sound should play. But it doesn't.

Eclipse also doesn't give me any suggestions when I try to code-complete inside the Runnable. Printing to the console works.

How should this be done?

Comment: Seems to work okay for me, perhaps you should provide a runnable example where it doesn't

Comment: It plays the sound for you? It doesn't for me..

Comment: Make sure you're volumes turned up

Comment: Oh... Just fixed it... double-checked system sounds on sound mixer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound was actually playing.

Make sure to check if your System Sounds are tuned up, or else you won't be able to hear the System BEEP sound.